# How to update ruby gem dependency? Must I rebuild it? How?

Tags: ruby, rspec, rubygems

I have a gem already installed locally, and I wanna add a new dependency into it. I worked with below steps:

1. Open the gem installation folder as below:
   `/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/nesta-0.10.0`
2. Add new dependency below into gemspec file (nesta.gemspec)
   `s.add_dependency('stacktracer', '>= 0.0.1')`
3. Append `gem 'stacktracer'` into `Gemfile`
4. Add `require "stacktracer"` into `Rakefile`
5. Run command `bundle update nesta`
6. Run command `bundle install`
7. Check `Gemfile.lock`, I already found the new dependency like below:

I have next dependencies:

```
DEPENDENCIES
debugger
mr-sparkle (>= 0.0.2)
nesta!
rack-test (= 0.6.1)
rspec (~> 2.14.0)
**stacktracer**
test-unit (= 1.2.3)
webrat (~> 0.7.3)
```

But when I met two problems here:

1. run command `gem dependency nesta`, I did not find stacktracer dependency list.
2. I added `require "stacktracer"` into `app.rb`, then run the application, it failed due to below error:

   ```
   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/nesta-0.10.0/lib/nesta/app.rb:4:in `require': cannot load such file -- stacktracer (LoadError)
   ```

Could any one help me to tackle the problems? Is there any approach that could manage to update gem dependency successfully?

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to edit the unpacked gems under `.../rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems`. If you need to update the alien gem, you are to follow this approach:

1. Fork the gem source at [github](https://github.com/gma/nesta)
2. Clone the repo to your local drive
3. Update whatever you want + update version
4. Set the dependency in your `Gemfile` to either use unpacked version or *your* git:

   - `gem 'nesta', :path => '.../nesta.git'`
   - `gem 'nesta', :git => 'git://...'`

Don’t forget to eliminate the original gem presence over your system. Hope it helps.

Comment: Really appreciated your answers, I understood that. I downloaded nesta-0.10.0.gem from https://rubygems.org/gems/json, then gem install it. Is there a way to start with nesta-0.10.0.gem to update its dependency? Because I did not find its source code on github.

Comment: Would you mind to click the link I have provided? It leads directly to nesta’s source code @github. You nevertheless should be update the source and version and then reinstall gem.

Comment: Sure, I will, thanks so much. BTW, if I only have a gem file, could I unpack it with command 'gem unpack' and then modify files to rebuild it into a new gem file?

Comment: Sure you can. Don’t forget to update the version to force `gem` to replace the obsolete original with your modified version.

Comment: Sorry to interfere you again. I did below steps: 1). Run command 'gem unpack nesta-0.10.0.gem' 2). cd to nesta-0.10.0  3). Add new dependency into nesta.gemspec 4). Append gem 'stacktracer','= 0.0.1' into Gemfile. 5). Add require 'stacktracer' into app.rb  6) Change version in version.rb 7). gem build nesta.gemspec.   After above steps, the nesta-0.10.1 is built out but it did not contain any file. I am wondering where the problem is.

Comment: You need to look at `nesta.gemspec`. There should be the string like `spec.files = \`git ls-files -z\`.split("\x0")`. Since you want to build the gem from unpacked sources (which obviously do not contain any git info within,) you should specify the correct list. Try, for instance, `\`find . -type f\`` for all files to be included.